# multiple random images in HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying draw multiple images from array at random on canvas. i cant figure out a way to iterate in array and draw when a function is calling draw() from  for loop.

this is what i have

```
// Call Draw particles
      for (var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
        particles[i].draw(i);
      };
```

and the draw ()

```
Particle.prototype.draw = function(i) {
        imgs = new Image();
        if (i<20){
            imgs.src = imgArray[1];
            ctx.drawImage(imgs ,this.position.x + this.parallaxOffsetX, this.position.y + this.parallaxOffsetY);
        }else if(i>20 && i<50 ){
            imgs.src = imgArray[2];
            ctx.drawImage(imgs ,this.position.x + this.parallaxOffsetX, this.position.y + this.parallaxOffsetY);
        }else if(i>50 && i<100){
            imgs.src = imgArray[3];
            ctx.drawImage(imgs ,this.position.x + this.parallaxOffsetX, this.position.y + this.parallaxOffsetY);
        }else{
            imgs.src = imgArray[4];
            ctx.drawImage(imgs ,this.position.x + this.parallaxOffsetX, this.position.y + this.parallaxOffsetY);
        }
    };
```

i know i need to figure out a way to loop in imgArray without using if else but i don't know how?

Thanks in advance..

edit:
here is a codepen demo [codepen](https://codepen.io/artndes9/pen/dRgbdg) using @mintychai advice

Comment: Your problem is drawing images in random? If yes, why you does not use function random in javascript? https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to use a random image from `imgArray` for each particle whereas right now you're giving particles their images based on their position in the particle array.

Also assuming you have 4 images in your `imgArray`.

```
Particle.prototype.draw = function(i) {
    imgs = new Image();
    var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
    imgs.src = imgArray[randomNumber];
    ctx.drawImage(imgs ,this.position.x + this.parallaxOffsetX, this.position.y + this.parallaxOffsetY);
};
```

[`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) gets you a random number, and what you're looking for is under the section "Getting a random integer between two values" in this resource.

Comment: Also not related to your question but some advice for your code: in your if-else statements you don't need to put `ctx.drawImage...` in each if block since it's the same for every one. Also not sure if your array is indexed at 1? It's good practice to start at 0.

Comment: the problem in calling math.random from here is it keeps redrawing the same particle position over and over because the random value for the same position changes next time the `draw()` function is called.

Comment: Thanks for your idea, i used this to generate a number between `var randomNumber = Math.floor(i / (particles.length / imgArray.length)); `. is it good or is there any other way

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean the problem is? In your CodePen it looks like they're being drawn in different positions.